# Bounded sequence in L1 ,counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm looking for the simpliest counterexample, that bounded sequences in $L^1(\Omega)$ with $|\Omega|<\infty$ may not have weakly convergent subsequence. I'd appreciate if you could at least give me any reference where I can find it.

Thanks in advance,
K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\Omega = (0,1)$, 
$$
\phi_n(x) = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x),
$$
where $\chi_M(x)$ is the characteristic function of the set $M$.

The sequence is bounded, $\|\phi_n\|_{L^1}=1$, but does not converge weakly.

In fact, if the sequence is interpreted as a sequence in the space $C([0,1])^*$, then the sequence converges weak-star towards the Dirac delta at $0$, $\phi_n\rightharpoonup^* \delta_0$ in $C([0,1])^*$.

Comment: why does the sequence not converge weakly?